# Datagridview change color based on condition code not working

Tags: c#, datagridview

Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

2,Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
{
    var mydatetime = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);

    if (mydatetime.Hour > 9 && mydatetime.Minute > 30)
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert that argument to `Parse()` method to `string` and that's what it's complaining about

```
var mydatetime = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: I did but cell/row color not changing.. please help i put this code in gridview_cell formating

Comment: Remember i have Clock In column data type time in database

Comment: Below Code is not working.. Cell did not change color................................private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
            {

                var mydatetime = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());

                if (mydatetime.Hour > 9 && mydatetime.Minute > 30)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Either pass a string to `DateTime.Parse`

```
DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
```

or use `Convert.ToDateTime`, which accepts `object`:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
```